# Perl 6 namespace and module system

Tags: perl, naming-conventions, raku

I'm pretty new to Perl and Perl 6.  And I can't get along with Perl 6 module/namespace/package system.

I'm working on a library. Say the name of my company is `MyCompany`. And the library is the "category" `Net`. So what should my file hierarchy look like? Should it be `lib/MyCompany/Net/MyLibrary.pm`? Or `lib/Net/MyLibrary.pm`? Or something else?

Also, should I wrap my class definition into something like this?

```
package MyCompany {
  class Net::MyLibrary {
```

Comment: If you're new to perl, you may want to consider holding off on Perl6 - it hasn't been widely adopted.

Comment: To add to what @Sobrique said, Perl6 hasn't even been officially released. I would also wait if you are wanting to be efficient and need to get work done now (Perl6 has far fewer resources for learning, of course).

Answer (score 3):

For the first part, the `::` is still the directory separator so it should be clear how packages are set up by looking around on CPAN or Github. This gives classes meaning about what they do and how they are related, though it is subjective. For the second question, you are mixing Perl 5 and Perl6 syntax here. There are two ways to declare classes in Perl6. The first is the familiar way in Perl 5 (except with the much more descriptive `class` statement);

```
unit class MyCompany;
```

`unit` tells Perl 6 that the class will extend to the end of the file (just like `package MyCompany;` extends to the end of the file in a Perl 5 module, or until another `package ..` statement). You can also declare classes and roles with blocks as you did above.

```
class MyCompany { # so begins the MyCompany class
    method foo {
        return self;
    }

    ## ...other methods
} # the end of MyCompany

# code from other classes...
```

And everything in the block would belong to class you declared.

Comment: `unit` is used to introduce a module or class when the semicolon form is used.

Comment: semicolon form is the first one, where you see `unit`, as opposed to the block form which is below that.

Comment: Just a quibble: a Perl 5 package is lexically scoped, so it ends at the enclosing scope end. The file is a scope. So, the package declaration will end at the scope end or when there's another package declaration in the same scope.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that it is really up to you. There are no rules about whether the name of a module should include your company name or its category name. You can just call it `MyLibrary` and it will work fine

If you're writing a large suite of libraries, or you want to fit in with an existing library structure, then you need to establish that structure and follow its rules

If you're concerned about names clashing with existing CPAN modules, then it's a good idea to use a special prefix. Your company name would do, so all your packages will begin with `MyCompany::`. What you put after that is your choice, but it makes sense to categorise your modules in some way

On the other hand, if you're writing something that you want to upload to CPAN that fits into the schemes there, then you should start your package name with `Net::`, `HTML::`, `Math::` etc.

So, suppose you want to write a network module for use in programs that may also use some modules from CPAN. Starting the name with `MyCompany::` will protect you from clashes with other packages. Then you may want `Net::` to keep your own category or network modules. And then you will want a unique name within `MyCompany::Net::`, like `MyModule`, but I hope it would be more expressive

Then your package would be `MyCompany::Net::MyModule` and the source code would be in file `MyCompany/Net/MyModule.pm`. Note that all segments should start with a capital letter